# Select multiple rows from a table and return the sum of the amounts column in a div

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to select multiple rows from a table and return the sum of the amounts column in a div.

This is my html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of articulos; index as i" (click)="sumarCantidad(i)">
    <td>{{item.articulo}}</td>
    <td>{{item.cantidad}}</td>
    <td>{{item.recogida}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is my ts:

```
  sumarCantidad(i: number){
    const valor = this.articulos[i].cantidad;
    this.articulos[i].cantidad = +valor
    alert(valor);
  }
```

I have managed to get the value of the quantity when I select a row but what I need is to select several rows and it returns the sum of the quantities of the selected rows in a div.

Can somebody help me?

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vgi4.jpg)

Comment: What does  `this.articulos[i].cantidad = +valor` this line means?

Comment: The amount will be the value of the alert

Comment: sumarCantidad(i: number) {
    this.articulos[i].selected = !this.articulos[i].selected; // toggle the selected property
    let sum = 0;
    for (const item of this.articulos) {
        if (item.selected) {
            sum += item.cantidad;
        }
    }
    this.total = sum;
}